Set style of multiple words based on first character
I have a series of quotes stored in single column table rows in Word 365 (Version 2403, Build 16.0).
I need to adjust the formatting of the quote attribution.
The format of each quote/row is:
This is a quote.
- Attribution Name
This is a quote.
- Attribution 
This is a quote.
- Attribution123

The Attribution may be 1 or 2 words of alphanumeric characters.
I need to format all characters after the "- ". Currently, my attempts format up until the space after the first word. It works on single name attributions.
My current code:
Sub DashFormat()
'
' DashFormat Macro
'
'
    
    With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Forward = True
        .Format = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .Text = "- [A-z0-9]@>"
        .Replacement.Style = "Subtle Emphasis"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub

The above applies the style to everything after the - except " Name".
I understand all of this except the function of @> at the end of the .Text string. I know that it doesn't work without the addition of some character specification in brackets before it.
I tried adding a space in the brackets.
I tried indicating space Chr codes.
I played with wildcards and escape characters.
Can anyone help design the query or explain the function of @>?


As zero or more occurrences {0,n} is not supported by Word wildcards searching, so two matching pattern are used. Maybe someone could provide simpler solution.

Find and Replace using wildcards

@ is used to find re-occurrences of the previous character (if any)


> is used to mark the end of a word

Sub DashFormat()
    With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Forward = True
        .Format = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .Text = "- [A-z0-9]@>"
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Style = "Subtle Emphasis"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .Text = "- [A-z0-9]@> [A-z0-9]@>"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub


Update:
Sub DashFormat()
    Dim docRng As Range
    Set docRng = ActiveDocument.Content
    With docRng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Forward = True
        .Format = False
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .Text = "- [A-z0-9]@>"
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        Do While .Execute
            docRng.Expand Unit:=wdSentence
            If UBound(Split(docRng.Text)) < 3 Then
                docRng.Style = "Subtle Emphasis"
                docRng.Collapse Word.wdCollapseEnd
            End If
        Loop
    End With
End Sub


When I try to run this, it locks up entirely. I've noticed that happens if I change anything during or after the @>. My guess is that during the second call it's causing some sort of loop, though I still have no idea what. Thank you for explaining @ and > though.

No, u can comment out the first Repalce and test the second one. I've tested the code without issues. Restart Word and test the code on a simple doc.

This doesn't work when the quote is in a table. If I remove the quotes from the table and put it without any structure, the code runs as intended. However, when the attribution ends at the end of the cell, this freezes. Could it be because of the special formatting or character at the end of a cell?

The second replacement seems to be getting stuck in a cell (if the attribution ends at the end of the cell), causing Word to become unresponsive. I'm not sure of the reason behind this. I've posted a workaround code as an alternative solution.

This works well, I added an Else statement during the Do While loop to prevent crashes if future attributions have more than 2 words/names.
